# react natvie not redirecting when axios is success

Tags: react-native

i am doing a axios post request the api call is sucess but the issue here is that i have to click on the sceen of emulator for the    `props.navigation.navigate('Home_scrren', {data: Data56});`  to redirect to the next screen i dont know why this is happening

```
 axios({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register',
     data: Data56,
   })
  .then(res => {
       if (res.status == 200) {
         props.navigation.navigate('Home_scrren', {data: Data56});
       }
     })
     .catch(error => {
       alert(JSON.stringify(error));
     });
 }
```

Comment: What does your Navigation stack/tab/drawer look like? Also `'Home_scrren'` looks like a typo

Comment: @PhantomSpooks i dont undestand can u expalin

Comment: Share your navigator class aswell.

Comment: It looks like `props.navigation.navigate('Home_scrren')` should be `props.navigation.navigate('Home_screen')`